# ASP.NET Core MVC - Creating a RequiredIf Attribute using IClientModelValidator

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a RequiredIf attribute in Core 2.0 using the IClientModelValidator. I've reviewed numerous threads on here trying to get it solved for myself, but for some reason it's not working as expected.

Basically, I want it so that if the property EmpTypeSelected is equal to "Contractor" I want to require that the user enters a value for CompanyName.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [EmpTypeCompanyRequired("EmpTypeSelected", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a company name.")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmpTypes { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an Employee Type")]
    public string EmpTypeSelected { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Employee Type")]
    public string EmpTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class EmpTypeCompanyRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private readonly string _comparisonProperty;

    public EmpTypeCompanyRequiredAttribute(string comparisonProperty)
    {
        _comparisonProperty = comparisonProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString;
        var contractorTypeValue = "Contractor";

        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_comparisonProperty);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property with this name not found");

        var comparisonValue = (string) property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        if (contractorTypeValue == comparisonValue)
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var error = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-error", error);
    }

    private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return false;
        }

        attributes.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The View looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpTypeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmpTypeSelected, new SelectList(@Model.EmpTypes, "Value", "Text", Model.EmpTypeSelected), new { id = "EmpTypeSelected", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpTypeSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing so that this has client side validation?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the View look like?

Comment: @AndrewReese I added the view html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller try something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // There was a validation error => redisplay the view so 
        // that the user can fix it
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        //Return View/Or Redirect

    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Query)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Query)
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
}
```